# A probability density function

Tags: distributions, density-function

In my project, I stumbled upon this probability density function:

$$ \frac{2^{1+d/2} \Gamma(4) \Gamma(\frac{d+1}2+1)}{\sqrt \pi \, \Gamma(6+d)} \, _1F_2\left( \frac{d+1}2+1 ; \frac{d+6}2 ; \frac{d+7}2 ; -\frac{z^2}4\right) $$

where $_1F_2$ is the [Generalized hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function)

I were wondering whether this was the probability density function of a "known"/named/studied distribution.

Comment: Try simplifying those Gamma functions into a Beta function.

Comment: What is the range for $z$?

Comment: Its range is [-pi; pi]